mysqldump: Error in field count for table: aborting
My Environment

Azure Flexible Server MySQL
MySQL version 8.0
mysqldump  Ver 10.14 Distrib 5.5.68-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

I am trying to backup a MySQL database using mysqldump, and I am having a hard time understanding what is going on. The same process works in the Preproduction environment, but it does not in Production. We have the same Azure MySQL flexible distribution, tier and DB version.
We use a Linux VM in PRE and another one in PRO where I have a MySQL client installed, same version in both environments. The only difference is that the Preproduction VM is RedHat 8, meanwhile the PRO VM is still RedHat 7.
Preproduction
[lvmadmn101@hcbae2c01lvm101 ~]$ mysql -u mysqladmn001 -p'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -h xxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com -P 3306 --ssl=true
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 570801
Server version: 8.0.36-cluster Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]> use mdp;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MySQL [mdp]> show columns from targetproject ;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra                    |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
| my_row_id  | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment INVISIBLE |
| PROJNAME   | varchar(64)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
| TYPENAME   | varchar(32)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
| TARGETNAME | varchar(32)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.004 sec)

MySQL [mdp]> select count(*) from targetproject ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        8 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.025 sec)

MySQL [mdp]>

Now, running mysqldump here works without issues.
[lvmadmn101@hcbae2c01lvm101 ~]$  /usr/bin/mysqldump --host=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com --port=3306 --user=mysqladmn001 --ssl=true --verbose --databases mdp  > /pgupgrade/mysql/mdp_pre.sql
-- Connecting to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_execution...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_execution_context...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_execution_params...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_execution_seq...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_instance...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_job_seq...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_step_execution...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_step_execution_context...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table batch_step_execution_seq...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table config...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table docerror...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table docmsg...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table mapmeta...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table maptypes...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table nodes...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table notif...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table postprocess...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table postproproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table preprocess...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table preproproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table proyect...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table source...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table spring_session...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table suscriber...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table suscription...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table target...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table targetproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table type_error_desc...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table users...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table usersproyect...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Disconnecting from hcbi1weupfsdmsmdpdata001.mysql.database.azure.com...
[lvmadmn101@hcbae2c01lvm101 ~]$

Production
Now, let's switch to the Production environment.
[lvmadmn015@hcbae2p01lvm015 mysql]$ mysql -u mysqladmn001 -p'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -h xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com -P 3306 --ssl=true
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6424
Server version: 8.0.36-cluster Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]> use mdp;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MySQL [mdp]> show columns from targetproject ;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra                    |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
| my_row_id  | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment INVISIBLE |
| PROJNAME   | varchar(64)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
| TYPENAME   | varchar(32)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
| TARGETNAME | varchar(32)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+--------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [mdp]> select count(*) from  targetproject ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        8 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Running mysqldump in Production produces this error:
[lvmadmn015@hcbae2p01lvm015 mysql]$ /usr/bin/mysqldump --host=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com --port=3306 --user=mysqladmn001 --ssl=true --verbose --databases mdp  > /pgupgrade/mysql/mdp_pro_1306.sql
-- Connecting to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mysql.database.azure.com...
-- Retrieving table structure for table config...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table docerror...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table docmsg...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table mapmeta...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table maptypes...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table nodes...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table notif...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table postprocess...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table postproproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table preprocess...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table preproproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table proyect...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table source...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table suscriber...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table suscription...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table target...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
-- Retrieving table structure for table targetproject...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
mysqldump: Error in field count for table: `targetproject` !  Aborting.
[lvmadmn015@hcbae2p01lvm015 mysql]$

I really don't understand the meaning of the error mysqldump: Error in field count for table: targetproject !  Aborting. There is no field called count in that table, and the invisible column cannot be, because is the same in PRE and it works there.
Does anyone knows what this error could be?
Thanks
Update
As requested by @RickJames, here the show create table
MySQL [mdp]> SHOW CREATE TABLE targetproject;
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| targetproject | CREATE TABLE `targetproject` (
  `my_row_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT /*!80023 INVISIBLE */,
  `PROJNAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `TYPENAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `TARGETNAME` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`my_row_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TARGETPROJECT_IDX` (`TYPENAME`,`TARGETNAME`,`PROJNAME`),
  KEY `SQL180201113810280` (`TARGETNAME`),
  KEY `SQL180201113731870` (`PROJNAME`),
  CONSTRAINT `TP_P` FOREIGN KEY (`PROJNAME`) REFERENCES `proyect` (`NAME`),
  CONSTRAINT `TP_T` FOREIGN KEY (`TARGETNAME`) REFERENCES `target` (`NAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


This would be a better fit on [DBA.se]

@TangentiallyPerpendicular it could fit in the other board, but there are tons of questions/answers here related to mysqldump

Why do you expect a mysqldump created for mariadb several years ago to work with a current release of mysql? And yeah, this question has nothing to do with programming or sw development, should have been asked on the DBA sister site of SO.

i am guessing that your tablespace could be corrupted please run https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysqlcheck.html but read all carefully and make a complete backup from your system before hand

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE targetproject.

@RickJames I updated the question

This has something to do with the Generated Invisible Primary Key (GIPK) in the table (which is the invisible my_row_id column).
I have a database on Azure Flexible Server MySQL which exhibits the same behaviour. In recent versions of mysqldump you can use the option  --skip-generated-invisible-primary-key which resolved the issue for me.

So from the code the error is comparing the number of fields returned by:
SELECT * FROM table
with the previous num_fields, which is the number of rows from the information_schema query:
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` AS `Field`,
`COLUMN_TYPE` AS `Type`,
`IS_NULLABLE` AS `Null`,
`COLUMN_KEY` AS `Key`,
`COLUMN_DEFAULT` AS `Default`,
`EXTRA` AS `Extra`,
`COLUMN_COMMENT` AS `Comment`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE
TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s' AND TABLE_NAME = '%s'

Strangely enough MariaDB-5.5.68 from 2020-05-12 didn't do much testing with MySQL-8.0.36 from 2024-01-16

but in this case, the problem should be happening in both PRE and PRO, where versions of MySQL and MariaDB are identical.
